# 'Development dashboard' web application

Tags: web-development, web-applications, deployment

I am not sure if something like this exists in that it is ready **out of the box**.

I currently have some web space that I use for various projects, and I would like to setup an area for some friends and I to develop web applications together.

My ideal setup would be to create a folder, say, webdev.domain.com.  We could all go to this domain, login, and then be able to setup new applications, pick which language will be used, setup database tables, allow HTML based file uploading, and create sub-folders to basically have a test bed for the applications.  In retrospect, it seems like I'm describing a limited version of cpanel.

I could come up with something in Drupal I'm sure, but I don't want to have to really spend time configuring much.  Like I said, I want to install it and have minimal configuration.

Does something like this exist (preferably in open-source)?

Answer (score 2):

"Develop web applications," "pick a language"... that's programmer talk. You want source control, not a web app: look into [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).

There's a learning curve if you've never used an SCM, but it's a rite of passage for any web dev, just like the moment when you realize someone overwrote 2000+ lines of your code that you just started overwriting as well, and the drunk googling for how-to's that usually happens a couple hours after that. Bad scene, easy to avoid.

If you need a web interface, try [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitHosting) for hosting, host your own [gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) (various PHP, Ruby, and Perl apps), or just use a [GUI client](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). I just keep my private/commercial git repositories spread out on dev servers and a couple laptops, easy & cheap as long as you have permissions to install it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would be what you're looking for as it's a hosted solution, but it's one option you can lean towards if you don't feel like developing a custom panel. The site is called [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) and it features free hosting (along with paid hosting). Downside to the free hosting is that you have to have an open-source project.

As for a self-hosted solution, you can use something that comes packaged with cPanel's Fantastico installations. It's called [dotProject](http://dotproject.net), though the link here is probably a newer one. The one packaged with my cPanel's is older. It's fairly good at project management.

Both solutions include tasks, milestones, team/"staff" (respectively), and tickets.

Apology for advertisement, I've got a couple solutions hosted on Assembla's site located [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/atlantis-framework) and [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/rentools/stream).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The 'Downside to the free hosting is that you have to have an open-source project.' is kind of what turns me off to that solution...otherwise we'd just go with SourceForge

Comment: Well, the only one I know of is dotProject then. I'm sure there are others out there, but I've only dealt with dotProject personally. Downside - no repository support :(

Comment: I'll have to check into it then :)

Answer (score 0):

Kodingen.com might fit your needs. It offers collaboration space, messaging, etc. It's for web app development, but you could probably use it as a source code repository for offline apps too.